# Delete Firestore document and Tableview Cell at the same time

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

I have a messaging feature in my app so I have a collection of documents with all messages and a second collection that saves the most recent messages from different users.

In my View Controller I have a tableview that shows all the recent messages, when I delete a cell using my function all the data gets deleted as I want it to in Firestore.

I also remove it from my array and delete the the row.

My problem is that even tho the data has been removed from Firestore the cell is not being removed at the same time.

When i run my app in the simulaator again a second time the cell has been removed

Does anyone know why the cell does not get removed straight away

```
func deleteMessages(currentUid: String, userUid: String) {
    db.collection("messages").document(currentUid).collection(userUid).getDocuments { (snapshot, Error) in
        
        if let er = Error {
            
            print(er)
            
        } else {
            guard let snapshot = snapshot?.documents else {return}
            for snap in snapshot {
                
                let message = Message(dictionary: snap.data())
                let docId = message.docId
                
                db.collection("messages").document(currentUid).collection("recentMessages").document(userUid).delete()
                db.collection("messages").document(currentUid).collection(userUid).document(docId).delete()
                
            }
            
        }
    }
} 


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    let userUid = chats[indexPath.row].user.userUid
    
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.chats.remove(at: indexPath.row)
      
        deleteMessages(currentUid: currentUid , userUid: userUid)
        
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .delete
}
```

Comment: What is your data source for the table view? Removing the row will remove the row visually, however if your data source still has the message object whenever the table view reloads the row will come back.

Answer (score 0):

after removing you need to call tableView.reloadData() inside the mainQueue